# Show $-u''(x) = H(x)$ and $u'(-1) = u'(1) = 0$ has infinitely many weak solutions

Tags: boundary-value-problem, weak-derivatives

I want to show that the Neumann boundary value problem
$$
\begin{cases}
- u''(x) = H(x), & x \in (-1, 1)\\
u'(-1) = u'(1) = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $$H(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x > 0, \\ 0, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$ is the Heaviside function, is not uniquely solvable in the weak sense, by finding infinitely many solutions.

For the test space I choose $$H^1((-1, 1); \mathbb R) := \{ u \in L^2((-1, 1); \mathbb R): u' \in L^2((-1, 1); \mathbb R) \},$$ where $u'$ is the weak derivative of $u$.
We have
$$
- \int_{-1}^{1} u''(x) v(x) dx
= \int_{-1}^{1} u'(x) v'(x) dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{0}^{1} v(x) dx
= \int_{-1}^{1} H(x) v(x) dx
$$
Thus the weak formulation is: find $u \in H^1((-1, 1); \mathbb R)$ such that
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} u'(x) v'(x) dx
= \int_{0}^{1} v(x) dx
$$
for all $v \in H^1((-1, 1); \mathbb R)$.

My idea is to write the right side as
$$
\int_{0}^{1} v(x) dx
= v(1) - \int_{-1}^{1} \max(0, x) v'(x) dx.
$$
If $v(1)$ we zero (which its not) the solutions would be
$$
u_c(x)
= \begin{cases}
c, & x < 0, \\
c - \frac{x^2}{2}, & x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$$
for any constant $c \in \mathbb R$, as the weak derivative of $u_c$ is
$$
u_c'(x) = - \max(0, x).
$$
I know that I can represent $v(1) = \int_{-1}^{1} \delta(x - 1) v(x) dx$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution, but this hasn't helped. Can I maybe use the Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus of Variations (that is, $\int_{a}^{b} u(x) v'(x) dx = 0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{C}_{0}^{\infty}([a, b]; \mathbb R)$ implies the existence of a $c \in \mathbb R$ such that $u(x) = c$ almost everywhere)?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you have a linear (inhomogeneous) equation and you want to know how many solutions there are, one thing to try is suppose $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ are solutions and then ask, "What equation does $u_{1} - u_{2}$ solve?"  This is true even at the level of linear algebra (not just differential equations), as you probably know.

If we do that here, if $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ solve your equation, then $w = u_{1} - u_{2}$ is a solution of the equation
\begin{equation*}
-w'' = 0 \quad \text{in} \, \, (-1,1), \quad w'(-1) = w'(1) = 0.
\end{equation*}
Notice that any such function must be constant due to the boundary conditions.  (Look at the equation that $f = w'$ solves; or play clever tricks with the weak formulation.)  That is, $w \equiv C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$.  Hence $u_{1} \equiv u_{2} + C$.

I did not prove that there were two solutions; I just showed that any two solutions differ by a constant.  At the same time, rerunning the previous argument in reverse, we see that if $u$ is a solution, then so is $u + C$, no matter which constant $C$ I take.  That is, as soon as we have one solution, we have infinitely many.  (Again, this is consistent with linear algebra: a linear system has no solutions, a unique solution, or infinitely many.)

(The question now is: do you know that there *is* at least one solution?  The answer is yes at any rate.)

Comment: But how can I find the solutions explicitely?

Comment: Well, that's another question entirely!  Do note, however, that you only need one solution (call it $v$, say) since every other solution is simply $v + C$ for some constant $C$.  If you want to know how to find an explicit solution of your equation, I would suggest asking another question on this website (and making it clear it is an explicit solution you are after).  Writing down the explicit solution should be an exercise in ODE theory; I don't think you will have a problem finding someone to help.